# Is there a "Print Workflow" feature inside SharePoint Designer?

Tags: workflow

Is there a way that I can print out my workflow designs using SharePoint Designer? Currently, inside InfoPath, there is a "Rule Inspector" that contain a Print function that allow one to print out all the rules and logic. So, I was wondering if I can print out all the workflows inside my site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to Export it to Microsoft Visio Premium 2010, then you get a diagram of your workflow. Don't think its possible to print directly from SPD (unless you use print screen)

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/create-import-and-export-sharepoint-workflows-in-visio-HA101888007.aspx#_Toc265226190

Answer (score 0):

The snipping tool in office works way faster and is easy to use on a rectangular item like a workflow.  Just cut and paste rapidly into Word.

Answer (score 0):

I use the screen clipper in OneNote, its fast, its easy and I have a coherent, easy to document capture of the workflow.

When I am in dev mode on the workflow I may do this dozens of times and fortunately if you tell OneNote to use the keyboard shortcut for screen capture you can do it in seconds.